# Program to calculate age in seconds not working correctly

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a simple program that calculates a users age in seconds after they give their age in years. It works fine for ages 0-68 but any age of 69 or higher breaks the program and just spits out the same wrong number every time. The program is listed below and any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int age;

    cout << "Please enter your age in years ";
    cin  >> age; //Grabs the users age
    unsigned long long int result = age*365*24*60*60; //calculates the users age in seconds
    cout << "Your age in seconds is: " << result << " seconds";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to multiply by 365.25?

Comment: What is the value of ULLONG_MAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way C++ works here is basically:

```
int temp = age*365*24*60*60;
unsigned long long int result = static_cast<unsigned long long>(temp);
```

So, you can probably see that the expression will overflow an `int` at around 69 years old (on your architecture). So, you want to force the calculation to work in `unsigned long long`, so the easiest way is to force one of the values to be `unsigned long long`, which will make the expression also `unsigned long long`. For example:

```
unsigned long long int result = age*365ULL*24*60*60; //calculates the users age in seconds
//                                     ^^^ declare constant as type unsigned long long
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned Long int ranges from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

So for any value less than or equal to 68, age in seconds is 2,144,448,000 or less which falls within range.

However for Age 69, Age in seconds comes out to be 2,175,984,000 which overflows the range.

I advise using long Double.